# Append new json elements on a json file

Tags: android, json, file, logging

I am developing an app that executes data logging with a rate of 4 streams (15 bytes each) per second. I wanto to put that data in a json file, that shall be written every 4 seconds.

It's possible to append new json data to an existing json file, without the need to parse the actual file and append the new data and write again ?

I am asking this, because it isn't possible to hold the whole data on memory for a long amount of time and since the app it's performance intensive i want to know what the best solution would be.

Between read the whole file and write a new one again (remember 60 bytes per second) and store the data in a database and write one file at the end, which solution would be the best (in a performance view) ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It has a streaming writer. That should let you add json data without keeping the whole thing in memory.